# Are guest accounts within Salesforce's Use Policies, and if so, how would you create a guest account?

Tags: user-admin, guest-user

Not sure if a single "guest" account is okay within Salesforce's Acceptable Use Policy (AUP) - but if it is, I would like to know, using the Enterprise Edition, how to setup a user that is only able to read data and unable to edit any global or user configs?

- By read-only, I mean that there is no data viewable by another user
  that is not data tied to the guest-user data; guest-user data might
  include, but not be limited to the guest-user's email, password.
- By global configs, I mean any config that is viewable by another
  user.
- By user configs, I mean any config that is viewable by another user,
  or edits data related to the user such as email, password, etc.

Comment: AUP = "Acceptable Use Policy" right? Personally I don't understand what you mean by a "single guest account".

Comment: @KeithC: Yes, "Acceptable Use Policy" - my bad, updated the question to not use the acronym.  By guest-account, I mean a shared account used by more than person just to view data; think of it as an anonymous read-only account access that requires a password, and the user is unable to edit the user config for the account. If it's still not clear what I mean, guess without further clarification by you on exactly what is unclear, I do not know what else to say. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks that is clearer. So it sounds like sharing a username/password. Read-only access can be done through profiles or permission sets. But I don't know of any way to stop things like password reset or other User object changes. And I also don't know about "Acceptable Use Policy" but hopefully someone will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [SFDC Master Subscription Agreement](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_MSA.pdf)

> **4.2 Usage Limits.** Services and Content are subject to usage limits, including, for example, the quantities specified in Order Forms.
> Unless otherwise specified,
>
> **(a)** a quantity in an Order Form refers to
> Users, and the Service or Content may not be accessed by more than
> that number of Users,
>
> **(b)** a User’s password may not be shared with
> any other individual, and
>
> **(c)** a User identification may be reassigned
> to a new individual replacing one who no longer requires ongoing use
> of the Service or Content.

Our policy at every org I have ever been at is that if we have x user seats, we only have x real users - no shared seats

We also use separate user ids for each API program (this isn't directly covered by 4.2 above)

Comment: Yes, very aware of best practices, such as an API user-id, though as often the case, clients need a legal reason not to engage in a given behavior.

Comment: At one org I worked at (very large company), they negotiated with SFDC a reduced rate/mo/read-only-user. SFDC wasn't nuts about this but there was a carrot of future revenue from a larger org installed base.